# R Adjusted R Squared multiple Independent Variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

All,

I am trying to find a way to get all the adjusted r square values against the dependent variable where I have multiple independent variables.

ie. `lm(balance ~ price + cost + rate)`
adjusted r2 for Balance vs price, Balance vs cost
and Balance vs rate.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to fit univariate models: `lm(balance ~ price)`, `lm(balance ~ cost)`, `lm(balance ~ rate)` etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping to do it in one step instead of individual models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in `anscombe` and assuming y1 is the dependent variable and x1, x2 and x3 are the independent variables:

```
sapply(c("x1", "x2", "x3"), 
  function(nm) summary(lm(anscombe[c("y1", nm)]))$adj.r.squared)
```

giving these adjusted R squared values:

```
       x1        x2        x3 
0.6294916 0.6294916 0.6294916
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not make much sense to compute the adjusted R-squares for models with single predictors as its purpose is to penalize for adding more independent variables.

However, you can calculate your adjusted R-squares easily:

```
#Assume this is your data.frame

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(dep = rnorm(100,5,1),
                 pred1 = rnorm(100,2,1),
                 pred2 = rnorm(100,3,1),
                 pred3 = rnorm(100,4,1))

#Calculate the R-squares as squares of correlation coefficents

rsq <- cor(df)^2
diag(rsq) <- 0  
data.frame(rsq)

#Or alternatively (as proposed by 李哲源)

rsq <- cor(df[, 1], df[, -1]) ^ 2

#Calculate the adjusted R-squares by the formula used in summary.lm

1 - (1 - rsq[-1,1]) * ((100 - 1)/(100-1-1)) #100 is equal to n

#The results

     pred1        pred2        pred3 
-0.007725613  0.006652629 -0.008241297
```